# can't fetch data from mongodb and display that into html

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**model named Field.js**

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/SuperchainV1', { 
    useNewUrlParser: true });
    mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true);
    mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
    mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
    const db = mongoose.connection;
    const FieldSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    productID: {
    type: String
    },
    productName:{
    type: String
    },
    fieldLocation: {
    type: String
    },
    farmerName: {
    type: String
    },
    farmerMobile: {
    type: String
    },
    farmerNid: {
    type: String
    },
    date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
    }
    });


    const Field = mongoose.model('Field', FieldSchema);
    module.exports = Field;
```

**routes index.js**

```
   router.get('/dashboard', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
   let field = Field.find({})
   .sort({date:'desc'}).exec( (err, field) => {
    res.render('dashboard', field);
        });
     })
```

**dashboard.ejs where i want to display data after fetching**

```
    <div class="jumbotron">
       <p class="lead">
         <% field.productID %>
         <% field.productName %>
         <% field.fieldLocation %>
         <% field.farmerName %>
         <% field.farmerNumber %>
         <% field.farmerNid %>
        </p>
    </div>
```

**errors i get "field is not defined"**

I want to fetch data from collections fields and display all the data into a ejs page named dashboard i tried this but always get the error field is not defined.

Comment: `Field.find({})`? why have you passed empty object to `find`? as it will not return anything and then you are doing sort on it.

Comment: as far i know find method will return all the occurrences from Field

Comment: True - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Comment: Can you show us the outcome of `console.log(field);` right before the `res.render`?

Comment: You also need to add an `if (err) throw err;`

Comment: Server started on port 5000
[ { _id: 5c95f91237f968184b7059ab,
    productID: 'chili0001 ',
    productName: 'Red dry chili',
    fieldLocation: 'sherpur, Bogura, Bangladesh',
    farmerName: 'Zahid Mia',
    farmerMobile: '01793456789',
    farmerNid: '12345678910111213',
    date: 2019-03-23T09:14:58.976Z,
    __v: 0 } ]

Comment: @Zahid Hasan `let field = Field.find({})` Could you try without the assignment. Simply call `Field.find({})...`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use for loop in `ejs` template

```
<% for(var i=0; i < field.length; i++) { %>
   <div class="jumbotron">
       <p class="lead">
         <%= field[i].productID %>
         <%= field[i].productName %>
         <%= field[i].fieldLocation %>
         <%= field[i].farmerName %>
         <%= field[i].farmerNumber %>
         <%= field[i].farmerNid %>
        </p>
    </div>
<% } %>
```